# Temporarily Disable process in operating system with C#

Tags: c#, operating-system

I want to disable a process in operating system while my exe is running. If former process running when my process start it will be disable and after my exe closed it will continue to run.

I am using C#, I tried `process.kill` method in `System.Diagnostics` namespace but that function closes application permanently.

Comment: kill stops execution, you could just restart it - but it depends, what exactly are you trying to stop? is it a service?

Comment: Not service it is a .exe too. Suppose I am using C.exe  and starting B.exe wihh process.start then I am starging A.exe. After A.exe started to run B.exe will be disabled. Adter A.exe stopped by user B.exe wil resume.

Comment: Add a [mcve] and show a minimal example of what you do and describe better what you do pretend to do.

Comment: Here are my codes.

Comment: The thing you want to do is 'suspend' the process, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71257/suspend-process-in-c-sharp?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Thanks A lot. It worked for my project.

Answer (score 0):

```
Process A;
    Process B;
    Process C;

    private void findExes()
    {
        List<Process> allProcesses = Process.GetProcesses().ToList().OrderBy(p => p.ProcessName).ToList();

        A = allProcesses.Find(delegate(Process pro) { return pro.ProcessName == "A"; });
        B = allProcesses.Find(delegate(Process pro) { return pro.ProcessName == "B"; });
        C = allProcesses.Find(delegate(Process pro) { return pro.ProcessName == "C"; });

    }
    private void stopAExe_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        findExes();

        if (A != null)
            A.Kill();

        if (  B != null)
        {
            /// RESUME B.EXE 
            /// B.EXE WİLL CONTİNUE 
        }
    }

    private void startAExe_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        findExes();
        if (A == null)
        {
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.FileName = @"A.exe";
            Process.Start(startInfo);

            if (B != null)
            {
                /// 
                /// DİSABLE B.EXE  ? 
            }
        }
    }

    private void startBExe_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        findExes();

        if (  B == null)
        {
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.FileName = @"B.exe";
            Process.Start(startInfo);
        } 
    }
```