# How to pause and resume child processes in C#?

Tags: c#, .net-core, process, system.diagnostics

in C# I start a cmd process which starts other processes.
I can kill the process and all child processes using

> Proc.Kill(true);

But it's like to know how to pause and resume all the child processes to a process?

Comment: Sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you *actually* trying to achieve?

Comment: Also, this might depend on the operating system used. Here is a question and answer for Windows: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71257/suspend-process-in-c-sharp