# How to freeze an application on windows

Tags: python, windows

I want to be able to freeze and resume a whole windows application at will. This is for non-native applications, mostly games. By freezing I mean stopping its process and resuming it afterwards as if no time skip happend.

This is a hard thing to look up as all question/solutions are for app builders or web pages. I'd prefer if the solution was in Python (due to other tools needed in future) but any other solution would be appreciated.

Comment: [Suspend all threads in the process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71257/suspend-process-in-c-sharp).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.